# Several Ubuntu sound problems when using headphones

Tags: 17.04, headphones, budgie

As in title I really suffer from many sound problems that make my ubuntu experience worse than ever.
To make long story short.

## First problem.

When I hear no sound there is complete silence, but when sound starts playing there is weird POP that is really annoying. It's not loud, but not quiet either. When sound stops playing, after few seconds it does this POP again. Like my laptop is turning on and off headphones so it is on only when sound is present.

## The second problem.

Now this was making my Ubuntu experience worse that i can imagine, i just want to roll back to windows because of this. That's the most frustrating thing ever. All the time when sound is not "muted" there is some annoying hissing, buzzing, white crackling sound playing ONLY in my headphones. It happens only in right speaker of my headphones, it happens only on my laptop and only in Ubuntu, tried other systems and it was fine, just on Linux i always had this problem, okay on windows.

I hope that someone would know how to solve those issues, with them i just can't stand using my laptop so i don't even do it, if it stays I'll have to reroll back to windows.

Comment: similar issue popped up on reddit - with a self-answer - https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/6ieqb6/irritating_ubuntu_things_that_make_me_want_to/

Comment: It helped with the first problem... but second one is still present, although the buzzing is a little bit silent...